# Excel formula to return a value based on specific range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there an easier way to write the equation w/o using too many AND conditions?
I am trying to return "Amount" based on the range within which the growth rate falls.

[image]

Comment: what if it was 1.25%?  Will there be gaps in your actual data? Or any overlaps?

Comment: Try: `XLOOKUP()` with approximate match or `VLOOKUP()` with approximate match

Comment: `=VLOOKUP(C4,$E$9:$G$10,3)`

Comment: You can remove the `Max` --> the higher bound column and in that column keep the amount, and can even use `=LOOKUP(C4,$E$9:$F$10)`

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the question. Yes there will be gap. As in the growth rate can be 0.6%, 1.75%.

Comment: No you still miss read the question. What @ScottCraner Sir has asked you, is that, in the screenshot you have shown the lower bound from `0.5%` -- and higher bound from `1.0%` and the next one was `1.5%` -- `2.0%` so when the `Growth Rate` is `1.25%` or `1.1%` what should be the amount? Will it be shown as a gap then? So if the rate is `0.6%` then it falls between `0.5%` -- `1.5%` and the amount will be 100 while for the other will be 200. Does that makes sense, or I am mistaking some where

Comment: No gap in the range. I updated the image. The ranges are increment of 0.5%. The vlookup approx. match works. Thanks for the answer. Any idea when the approx vlookup function can break in this scenario??

Comment: @Shank it will break if the min value is below `0.50%` since you have not defined the amount for the range `0.0%` -- `0.49%` hence giving you `#N/A` error also if its more than `2.0%` it will always show you 200.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting it as an answer to show how `LOOKUP()` Function can also be used.

[image]

---

As **[Scott Craner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4851590/scott-craner)** Sir, suggested you can use `VLOOKUP()` Function with approximate match

• Formula used in cell `C5`

```
=VLOOKUP(C4,$E$9:$G$10,3)
```

---

However, you can also use `LOOKUP()` Function, just like as the screenshot shown above,

• Formula used in cell `C6`

```
=LOOKUP(C4,$E$14:$F$15)
```

---